# when mouseout the element is moving out the correct place jquery

Tags: jquery

i mede this ridiculous exp.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fg9kr/9/)

why when the mouseover/out event happens, the element go to a diferent place ?

in my case, i have a `position: absolute;` and other css attr set in the span, so, when the mouseover happens, the span have a normal `fadeIn()` , but, the mouseout , with `fadeOut()` event, made the element back to other position, like position 0 of `absolute`

why this happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because, `fadeIn` set the display property of `span` element to `block` when it starts animation and span is an `inline` element so it should actually set it to 'inline' to appear at the right location.

Answer (score 0):

you can always do this (toggle opacity):

http://jsfiddle.net/AdpAb/